# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent while trying to run RingtoneService

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, service, android-mediaplayer

I am creating an organizer app which contains many functions one of them is an alarm, while trying to start the RingtoneService for my alarm most of the times I get this exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent" because it's running in the background (sometimes it runs with delay)!
I extensively searched for an answer and tried the following and none worked:
- JobScheduler : I get the same exception
- bindService() and writing the code inside onServiceConnected() : it never hits the onServiceConnected()

Below are the important parts of my code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

Broadcast call from activity below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class)
                .putExtra("ALARM_ON", true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Service class below:

```
public class RingtonePlayingService extends Service {

    // Player
    MediaPlayer player;
    boolean isRunning;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if (!isRunning) {

            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ringtone);
            player.start();

            this.isRunning = true;

            showNotification();

        }
        else if (isRunning) {

            player.stop();

            this.isRunning = false;

        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are getting this on Android 8.0+, you will need to switch to `startForegroundService()` and have your service call `startForeground()`.

Comment: @PeeGee Which OS version you are using to test it?

Comment: @CommonsWare, thank you, that solved my problem

Comment: @Sagar I am using Android 8.0, that was the problem I had

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running your code on Android 8.0 then this behavior is expected. Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services), starting from Android 8.0, you cannot start a service in background if your application is not in foreground. You need to replace following:

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

**Do**

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent );
```

Ensure to call `startForeground()` in your onHandleIntent with notification. You can refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111860/oreo-foreground-service-does-not-show-foreground-notification) for details to implement it.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem!

`Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);
            context.startForegroundService(serviceIntent);`
and I called the `startForeground()` in `onCreate()` in my Service class instead of the onHandlerIntent and it works fine:
`public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initNotification();
        startForeground(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }`

Comment: `context.startForegroundService ()` is available from Android O. You need to either use `ContextCompat` or check version before calling it. You might have problem with older versions, since its not available in older versions. Remember to test on lower versions

Comment: This is not the optimal solution. You should not simply start bunch of long running foreground services. It is better to extend `JobIntentService` instead of `Service` and continue using `startService` which is a better solution.