# Start context.startService(intent) on Android Pie

Tags: android

I start a service on my activity's onResume, it worked fine on oreo but lately I have been seeing crashes for Android P, which says "Unable to resume Activity.... Not allowed to start service intent ... app is in background..". Has anyone seen this before and where able to apply fix, any input would be much appreciated.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Timber.v("onResume");
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Token.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_FETCH_TOKEN);
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

just to add more context, I have not been able to reproduce the crash myself.

Comment: Include your code.

Comment: It is as simple a code as it gets

Comment: protected void onResume() { super.onResume();   context.startService(intent); }

Comment: Edit your question to include the code. Where is the `intent` being declared?

Comment: Take a look at this question and the first answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961273/java-lang-illegalstateexception-not-allowed-to-start-service-intent-while-tryin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same Problem with a small Service which i didn't want to change to a ForegroundService. Then i found this workaround provided by Google for starting services in onResume:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    if (runningAppProcesses != null) {
        int importance = runningAppProcesses.get(0).importance;
        // higher importance has lower number (?)
        if (importance <= ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
            //start your service the same way you did before in here
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
```

> The issue has been addressed in future Android release.
>
> There is a workaround to avoid application crash. Applications can get
>   the process state in Activity.onResume() by calling
>   ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses() and avoid starting Service if
>   the importance level is lower than
>   ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND. If the
>   device hasn’t fully awake, activities would be paused immediately and
>   eventually be resumed again after its fully awake.

Comment: Good to know. Could you please share the source.

Answer (score 1):

On Oreo8+ you cannot start a background service if your application is not "shown", to do that you need to edit your code like below:

```
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume(); context.startForegroundService(intent);
 }
```

In onCreate() method of your service class you also need to add:

****EDITED* 2018-09-18 18:15***

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("My App")
                .setContentText("Doing some work...")
                .setContentIntent(pIntent).build();
startForeground(1000, notification);
```

Comment: This just crashes the app.

Comment: edit with a more complex way but it should work now. I think notification cannot be null.

Comment: yeah but i do not want to show a notification, the funny thing i do not understand is why on onResume, the App is still in background, that just does not make sense.

Comment: @MohammedAbdulBari, Post Oreo. No background concept. But you can run it in foreground. You have to use context.startForegroundService(intent); as Legion said. Now If you are starting a foreground service then you must create a notification in onCreate method only and at the end of onCreate you must use startForeground(111, mBuilder.build()); to start running your onStartCommand. These are rules with no excuses..!! If you do not want notification it clearly means you can not start service post Oreo. That is it.

Comment: @sandhyasasane the thing is I am not starting the service on background, it is a one time service started on Activity's onResume which means the app should already be in foreground, but for some reason it is not. Also the app does not crash for me on a pixel with Android 9 running on it.

Comment: @MohammedAbdulBari, In that case... You have no need to call service too.. Make a class that has a constructor which takes context as parameter and define a method and onresume create a object of that class with current context and call the method using that object... why service? And app is in background not in foreground while in onresume... Use onPostResume()

Comment: I agree with @sandhyasasane answer, btw if you need to use a service [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) 
 you can found a more detailed expanation :)

Comment: @MohammedAbdulBari did you find any good explanation as to why an app in Activity.onResume() is not in a foreground state? and did this solution work for you regardless?  BTW, I've seen this exact problem on Pixel 3 (9.0)

Comment: not really, instead of using a service I am now using a OneTimeWorkRequest. Funny thing was that we were seeing the same crash when we started our service in Activity.postResume().

Comment: @Mark let me know if you find anything I am still curious.