# Google Cloud Messaging - onRegistered not called on Android 9.0 Pie

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Before I begin, I understand that GCM is depreciated, but due to time and resource constraints on this ticket, I don't think migrating to FCM is feasible at this juncture.  I didn't write the app (the contractor who did it is long-gone by now), I just need to fix it if possible.  If it's not possible without doing a migration, I'd like to just relay that information onwards instead of continuing to bash my head against this any longer.

**My question, in short, is this:**  Was there anything introduced in Android 9.0 (API 28) that would preclude the GCM registration process from working?  The app works fine on all preceding versions of Android, but not Pie.

**More info:**  When the app starts on a fresh 9.0 device, a call to GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId() is made.  It returns a blank string, as expected. Intent filters are created, receiver is registered, etc.  Finally, a call to GCMRegistrar.register() is made.  On every other version of Android, I get a response with a registration token that gets fielded in the onRegistered method in the GCMIntentService class.  For some reason, this callback method is never called on devices running Pie.

**What I've tried:**  Already updated play-services-gcm to v16.0.0.  Min sdk is 14.  Target is 28.  Ran some debug broadcasts that target my receiver, it still functions.  Still can't find a good reason why onRegistered suddenly isn't being called on this version of Android.

I'm more or less unconcerned about the code and/or manifest because, again, it has been chugging along fine on hundreds of devices for many years now.  Did Google just cut life support for GCM registration at the OS level with Pie or something?  If not, are there Pie-specific changes that need to be made to get it to work?  Looking at Google's documentation, their solution seems to be "migrate to FCM", but as I mentioned before, that's not an option at the moment.

Comment: Does it fail on all API 26+ devices? The [Background Service Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services) are going to limit when a service, like a `GCMIntentService` can actually be started.

Comment: Heya.  It only fails on API 28 devices.  API 26 still works fine.

Comment: According to the faqs, it'll be fully phased out by April of this year, but hasn't yet https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq.  Have you upgraded to the latest version of Google Play Services?  Personally I'd get a revised timelne and just migrate to FCM - it's relatively easy, and you'll definitely be required to in a couple of months anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, the rollout isn't supposed to come to full fruition until April of 2019.  With that said, it's hard to say without code, but depending on your implementation and that you mentioned the `GCMIntentService` it could have something to do with the changes to how background Services are allowed to run in Android Pie.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383953/start-context-startserviceintent-on-android-pie) for more details.

Check your logcat to see if you get any errors when trying to start the Service during the registration process.